# Usage of potential form of かける

Tags: grammar, verbs, conjugations

In the sentence

> 男に突然声をかけられた
>   駅までの道を知りたいらしい

I interpret this to mean "I yelled at the man so loud as if I wanted it to reach all the way to the station"

Is my translation correct? Why is the potential form of かける used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not the potential form, it's the passive form (which takes the same structure).

> I/he was suddenly approached by a man (called at) ....

On a different point, as the first half the sentence the second half should be too. (The sentence is still otherwise somewhat unnatural though)

> 男に突然声をかけられた 駅までの道を知りた**かった**らしい

Comment: I may be wrong, but the literal translation is "I was suddenly approached by a man," isn't it?

Comment: @naruto As the subject isn't specified, it could be either. I'll edit